# Create an Image Grid in Xaringan

Tags: html, css, r, xaringan

I'm trying to learn a bit more CSS/HTML to customize xaringan slides and could use some help.

I would like to place a number of GIF's in an image grid like [the one shown here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_image_grid.asp) into a xaringan slide.

[image]

I know that normally one can display two images side-by-side by either using `.pull-left[]` & `.pull-right[]` or by defining sections with custom CSS like this:

```
.left-code {
  color: #777;
  width: 38%;
  height: 92%;
  float: left;
}
.right-plot {
  width: 60%;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 1%;
}
```

Then one would put the images in a xaringan slide with R code like this:

```
.pull-left[
<img src=figure1.jpg>
]

.pull-right[
<img src=figure2.jpg>
]
```

For an image grid the custom CSS would be:

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

/* Create two equal columns that sits next to each other */
.column {
  flex: 50%;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.column img {
  margin-top: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

However, it also includes HTML code that specifies all of the images so I'm not quite sure how to integrate the two in a xaringan slide.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="wedding.jpg">
    <img src="rocks.jpg">
    <img src="falls2.jpg">
    <img src="paris.jpg">
    <img src="nature.jpg">
    <img src="mist.jpg">
    <img src="paris.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="underwater.jpg">
    <img src="ocean.jpg">
    <img src="wedding.jpg">
    <img src="mountainskies.jpg">
    <img src="rocks.jpg">
    <img src="underwater.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="wedding.jpg">
    <img src="rocks.jpg">
    <img src="falls2.jpg">
    <img src="paris.jpg">
    <img src="nature.jpg">
    <img src="mist.jpg">
    <img src="paris.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="underwater.jpg">
    <img src="ocean.jpg">
    <img src="wedding.jpg">
    <img src="mountainskies.jpg">
    <img src="rocks.jpg">
    <img src="underwater.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using the extension theme [here](https://github.com/emitanaka/ninja-theme). 
This theme is included the later version of `xaringan` so you can specify in the YAML by `css: "ninjutsu"`. The layout should look like below:

```
---
title: "Split to grid in `xaringan`"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: ["ninjutsu"]
---


class: split-four

.column[
<img src="wedding.jpg">
<img src="rocks.jpg">
<img src="falls2.jpg">
<img src="paris.jpg">
<img src="nature.jpg">
<img src="mist.jpg">
<img src="paris.jpg">
]

.column[
<img src="underwater.jpg">
<img src="ocean.jpg">
<img src="wedding.jpg">
<img src="mountainskies.jpg">
<img src="rocks.jpg">
<img src="underwater.jpg">
]

.column[
other images
]

.column[
other images
]
```